# how can I execute ajaxStart and ajaxEnd just one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to popup a loading gif when web page submitting ajax request, but how can I bind the loading function to each ajax request instead of bind to all ajax request, because some request do not need to popup loading window.

```
$("#genericSearchPage_window input[name=submit]").click(function(e){
    $("#genericSearchPage_window input[name=submit]").ajaxStart(function(){
        console.log("ajax started~!");
    });
    $.ajax({
        url:"genericSearch.genericSearch.html",
        data: $("#genericSearchPage_window #genericSearchForm").serializeJson(),
        dataType:"json"
    }).done(function(data){
        genericSearchProcess(data);
    });
});
```

at this function, the ajaxStart function did not work, if we change it to `$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
            console.log("ajax started~!");
        });`
it can work, but all ajax request will be bind this function :/
how can I deal with it

Comment: if putting it in a click handler why can't you just call the popup without ajaxStart? Otherwise could create a wrapper for `$.ajax` and pass `showPopup` as boolean argument. Also look at `settings` object to see if you can create a simple conditional in `ajaxStart`...see docs examples

Comment: @charlietfl you idea is cool, but I want to write this function as a common function just like a plugin, I can popup once button clicked, but how can I know the ajax request finish?

Comment: can use ajaxComplete to hide popup...if it's not visible do nothing

Comment: @charlietfl it is a good idea, I will have a try later, I am trying the deffered object.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your start method to be applied to **all** requests then maybe you can use the `beforeSend` callback on your request?

```
$.ajax({
    url:"genericSearch.genericSearch.html",
    data: $("#genericSearchPage_window #genericSearchForm").serializeJson(),
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
        console.log("ajax started~!");
    },
    dataType:"json"
}).done(function(data){
    genericSearchProcess(data);
});
```

Alternatively, look at the `global` property, which prevents the global methods like ajaxStart from being called.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"genericSearch.genericSearch.html",
    data: $("#genericSearchPage_window #genericSearchForm").serializeJson(),
    global: false,
    dataType:"json"
}).done(function(data){
    genericSearchProcess(data);
});
```